# CakePHP 3 - How do I use left joins in a query

Tags: mysql, left-join, cakephp-3.0

I have the following query that works, but after talking to the client I realized I need left joins to get the desired results and I don't know how to do it.

This is my query:

```
$query = $this->AssetStatusAudits->find('all', [
                'contain' => [
                    'AssetStatus',
                    'Users',
                    'Assets' => function ($q) {
                        return $q->contain([
                            'Employees',
                            'Sites'
                        ]);
                    }
                ],
                'conditions' => [
                    'AssetStatusAudits.created >' => $from,
                    'AssetStatusAudits.created <' => $to
                ]
            ]);

            $query->select([
                'createdDate' => 'date(AssetStatusAudits.created)',
                'assetStatus' => 'AssetStatus.desc_en',
                'firstName' => 'Users.first_name',
                'lastName' => 'Users.last_name',
                'count' => $query->func()
                    ->count('*')
            ])
                ->group('date(AssetStatusAudits.created)', 'assetStatus.desc_en', 'users.last_name')
                ->order('Users.last_name', 'Users.created');
```

The above query generates this in cake:

```
SELECT date(AssetStatusAudits.created) AS `createdDate`, 
AssetStatus.desc_en AS `assetStatus`, 
Users.first_name AS `firstName`, 
Users.last_name AS `lastName`, 
(COUNT(*)) AS `count` 
FROM asset_status_audits AssetStatusAudits 
INNER JOIN asset_status AssetStatus ON AssetStatus.id = (AssetStatusAudits.asset_status_id) 
INNER JOIN users Users ON Users.id = (AssetStatusAudits.user_id) 
INNER JOIN assets Assets ON Assets.id = (AssetStatusAudits.asset_id) 
LEFT JOIN employees Employees ON Employees.id = (Assets.employee_id) 
INNER JOIN sites Sites ON Sites.id = (Assets.site_id) 
WHERE (AssetStatusAudits.created > date('2016-01-13') AND AssetStatusAudits.created < date('2016-05-03')) 
GROUP BY date(AssetStatusAudits.created)  
ORDER BY Users.last_name
```

But this is the query that I need to add to cakePHP and I don't know how to do it:

```
SELECT 
date(asset_tracking.asset_status_audits.created) as 'Date',
asset_tracking.asset_status.desc_en as 'Status',
asset_tracking.users.first_name as 'First Name' ,
asset_tracking.users.last_name as 'Last Name',
count(*)
FROM asset_tracking.asset_status_audits
LEFT OUTER JOIN asset_tracking.assets ON asset_tracking.asset_status_audits.asset_id = asset_tracking.assets.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN asset_tracking.asset_status ON asset_tracking.asset_status_audits.asset_status_id = asset_tracking.asset_status.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN asset_tracking.users ON asset_tracking.asset_status_audits.user_id = asset_tracking.users.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN asset_tracking.employees ON asset_tracking.assets.employee_id = asset_tracking.employees.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN asset_tracking.sites ON asset_tracking.assets.site_id = asset_tracking.sites.id
WHERE asset_tracking.asset_status_audits.created between date('2016-01-13') and date('2016-05-19')
group by
date(asset_tracking.asset_status_audits.created) ,
asset_tracking.asset_status.desc_en,
asset_tracking.users.last_name
ORDER BY asset_tracking.users.last_name, asset_tracking.users.created;
```

Comment: and what is the query that cake generates instead?

Comment: @arilia - see edited question, I added the generated query in there.

Comment: what are the relationships between your models?

Comment: The joinTypes were all set to INNER...I changed them to LEFT and it seems to work now.